# How to overcome function overloading in System Verilog

Tags: oop, verilog, system-verilog

```
program automatic test;  
class A;  
    task get();  
        $display("A");  
    endtask  
endclass  
  
class B extends A;  
      
    task get(int a,int b);  
        $display("%d %d",a,b);  
    endtask  
endclass  
  
initial  
begin  
    B b = new();  
    b.get();  // Throws Error Because of Hiding
end  
  
endprogram: test
```

In C++ we can overcome this by making use of `using A::get` but in SV how to avoid function hiding and access the parent class function get()?

Comment: there is no *overloading* in system verilog. So, just use different names for the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function overloading was difficult to implement in SystemVerilog because of the weak type system in Verilog. What happens if you had function with an 32-bit input and overloaded it with a function with a 16-bit input, but called the function with an 8-bit value. Which one do you chose?

But there are really two distinct concerns here. Function overloading in C++ does not necessarily have to involve inheritance—you could declare both `get` functions in the same class. If you have functions with different prototypes and the caller needs to know which ones are available, you might as well give them unique names.

```
module automatic test;  
class A;  
    task get();  
        $display("A");  
    endtask  
endclass  
  
class B extends A;      
    task get2(int a,int b);  
        $display("%d %d",a,b);  
    endtask  
endclass  
  
initial  
begin  
    B b=new();  
    b.get();
    b.get2(1,2);
end  
endmodule: test
```

You could also take advantage of SystemVerilog's default argument feature to assign *unusable* values for your arguments

```
module automatic test;  
class A;  
    task get();  
        $display("A");  
    endtask  
endclass  
  
class B extends A;      
    task get(int a=-1,int b=-1);
        if (a<0) super.get();
        else $display("%d %d",a,b);  
    endtask  
endclass  
  
initial  
begin  
    B b=new();  
    b.get(); // indirectly calls A::get()
end  
endmodule: test
```

Addressing the other concern about accessing non-virtual members of a base class, you need to upcast the handle to a `A` class variable.

```
initial  
begin  
    B b=new();
    A a;
    a = b; 
    a.get();
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access the base class get method using the extended class object. But you can access it in extended class get method as below. Fixed couple of issues as well.

```
program automatic test;  
class A;  
    virtual task get();  
        $display("A");  
    endtask  
endclass  
  
class B extends A;  
      
    task get();  // Removed the arguments as during this method call in initial block, you were not passing anything. If you need arguments then pass some value during task call
      super.get(); // Using super you can access the base class get method
      A::get();  // Or you can also access it using class name and scope operator. This way is helpful when there is a deep down hierarchy 
      $display("B");  
    endtask  
endclass  
  
initial  
begin  
    B b=new(); // You didn't create the object
    b.get();
end  
  
endprogram: test
```

Comment: how do you propose to implement 'get' with 2 args in B?

Comment: 2 ways: 1) having the argument with default value 2) If arguments aren't having default values then pass the value during API call